# How can I remove a method from the class definition on the fly?

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode-manipulation

Let me start by saying that this is purely an exercise to satisfy my curiosity. This is not meant to be used in any sort of production environment.

What I would like to know is if it is in any way possible to redefine a class on the fly by removing/adding methods to its definition.

For example, given this class:

```
public class PersonBuilder {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public PersonBuilder name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("Name defined");
        return this;
    }

    public PersonBuilder age(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        System.out.println("Age defined");
        return this;
    }

}
```

What I want is to completely remove `name` from the class definition once it is invoked. Equivalent behavior is expected if I invoke `age`. Basically whichever method is invoked gets removed.

I understand this would require some level of bytecode manipulation, I'm fairly certain it cannot be achieved via reflection.

Anyway, I am looking for some guidance on how I could develop such behavior. Any tips will be very helpful.

Comment: Look at asm and other dynamic libraries.

Comment: refer JavaAssist , this may help you https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/CtClass.html#removeMethod-javassist.CtMethod-

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that even you find a way to do what you want (it is certainly possible) the code that call that methods is already compiled. This mean only practical outcome will be `NoMethodDefFound` exception at moment when method will be called second time.

So my solution is to create counter for method and check it each time you call this method. Throw exception when you called second time.

Of course this will not work with reflection.

Comment: I'd suggest use of [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) for this.

Comment: @Andreas for what?

Comment: To me it honestly doesn't matter if I return a new class e.g. `PersonBuilder2.java` as long as the *behavior* is the one I am looking for

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by return new `PersonBuilder2.java`.

Comment: For example, when I invoke `name` on `PersonBuilder` I create a new class named `PersonBuider2` that has no method `name` in its definition and then return it. At this point I am really just sort of brainstorming

Comment: This is pretty easy. There are lot of libraries that help manipulate bytecode. You just create new class and load it into `ClassLoader` with `defineClass` (it is protected method so you need your own classloader impl) then instantiate it. But it will be no difference with my solution.

Comment: @talex To inject the counting behavior your answer is talking about. Let the AOP library do the bytecode replacement or subclassing necessary to change the behavior, so you can focus on the important part, i.e. the behavior of passing the first call through and throwing an exception on any subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use some wrapper or proxy that throws an exception once method is invoked.

Or Method.setAccessible(false);